# How to set FTP stream context with PHP file_put_contents?

Tags: php, file, sockets, ftp, ip

I'm trying to add a `socket => array('bindto' => [IP])` stream context to a PHP call to `file_put_contents` using an FTP stream (can't use passive mode):

```
$ftpPath = 'ftp://user:password@host/path/to/write/file.txt';
$opts = array('socket' => array('bindto' => '[return ip addess]'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents($ftpPath, 'Test Content', 0, $context);
```

When I run the above, it looks like I'm able to connect properly to the remote server, but am getting an error 550 that the file doesn't exist - does that mean I'm connected but can't create the file? I've tried adding `ftp => array('overwrite' => true)` as a stream context option with the same result.

I've also tried just getting the file handle using `fopen`:

```
fopen($ftpPath, 'r', 0, $context);
```

but am getting a 'failed to open stream: FTP server reports 213' error.

Comment: Does the `path/to/write` path exists on the FTP server?

Comment: Why are you asking about "stream context", if your problem is actually completely different?

Comment: @Martin - yes - the path exists, but no file is created when either file_put_contents or fopen is run.

Comment: Do you have an access to FTP server log?

Comment: Nope. I only have limited access to the FTP server, so I could validate that the file is being copied, just no access to the log.

Comment: Can you do FTP session capture (e.g. using Wireshark)?